# Using Google Play Settings API resolve location settings from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, google-play-services

Using the [Google Play Location and Settings API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi) a developer can easily check if the Android device's location settings are correct.

The API also supports fixing any settings that are not correct using the [`startResolutionForResult`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/Status#startResolutionForResult%28android.app.Activity,%20int%29) method.  (It calls [`Activity.startActivityForResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) and provides feedback of users "yes/no" choice in the activities `onActivityResult()` method.)

This all works fine so far, except that I am calling `startResolutionForResult` from a fragment.  As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6147884/8524), an intent needs to called via `Fragment.startActivityForResult()` for the result to be given to the fragment as well.

Is there any way of getting this result to the fragment?  I was half expecting a `createIntentForResolutionForResult` on the [ResultStatus](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/Status) class.  Ideally I don't want to modify my containing Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `super.onActivityResult` on the Activity and call your Fragment from there. Otherwise its presence is there just for the sake of it and no work is done on the calling method which is *startResolutionForResult* in this case. Check the source of [FragmentActivity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.java).